# DateTime.Today returns wrong Hours / minutes

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

When I make an output for:

```
DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy_HH-mm_tt");
```

It returns me "08-09-2013_00-00_a.m." instead of "08-09-2013_10-36_p.m." (my current system hour).

What causes this behaviour? Thank you..

Comment: Use `DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy_HH-mm_tt");`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `DateTime.Now`:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy_HH-mm_tt");
```

`DateTime.Today` gives you the date part of current time with the time component set to `00:00:00`.

[See msdn documentation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today.aspx)

Comment: Ooops I just saw that msdn article a few mins ago, and didn't read that line lol

Answer (score 1):

Use DateTime.Now.

Additional info if you want to compare time.

```
        DateTime start = new DateTime(2013, 6, 14,2,15,20);
        DateTime end = new DateTime(20013, 12, 14);
        TimeSpan difference = end - start;
        int haha = difference.Minutes;
        Console.WriteLine("Difference in days: " + difference.TotalMinutes);
```